# Cannot RDP into my home machine from work, despite netcat saying the port is open

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, pfsense

I am trying to remote (RDP) from my work machine (Windows 10) to my home machine (also Win10). I use a **pfSense** router/firewall at home, so I configured a NAT rule like so:
 - Interface: WAN
 - Protocol: TCP
 - Source address: (my work public IP)
 - Source port: * (any)
 - Destination address: WAN net
 - Destination port: 3389 (MS RDP)
 - NAT IP: 192.168.1.120 (home machine private IP)
 - Description: RDP from work to home

I am testing the rule with **netcat** on my work machine like so:
`me@work-pc:/$ nc -zv (my_home_public_IP) 3389
Connection to (my_home_public_IP) 3389 port [tcp/*] succeeded!`

However, when I try to RDP to my home machine, the connection fails (times out). Thinking there is something here at work blocking the connection, I spoke with a Network Engineer and he assured me, no, there is nothing blocking it.

As an aside: I can successfully connect to my Mac via VNC-tunneled-over-SSH, and both of those firewall NAT rules are setup the same on the pfSense. However, when I try to point the RDP rule to another Windows machine on my home LAN, it also fails.

How can I troubleshoot this, Wireshark?

Comment: I'm almost certain that the return RDP traffic is blocked, but I cannot verify that.

Comment: My coworker confirmed: RDP outbound/inbound is blocked on our network.